# How to fix a coroutine was expected error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, pyrogram

I tried to start a *pyrogram* client with `loop.create_task(app.start())` but get an error `TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <pyrogram.client.Client object at 0x7f8bb7580520>`. How can I fix it?

```
import asyncio

from pyrogram import Client

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = Client(
"aaaaa",
bot_token="token",
api_id=12,
api_hash="a"
)

loop.create_task(app.start())
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 . If you're *confident* that the code has *not changed* since the last time that it worked, then there are two possibilities: either you're wrong about that, or a new version of the library changed the interface. You should start by trying to read the documentation. If you are rewriting code that you "know worked" a year ago when you wrote it totally the same way, for sure, though - the smart money is on the first option. (But then, you probably should still start by reading the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Pyrogram Client already has an event loop, you don't need to create again. If you follow the [documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) it's clear how to run the bot.

Also you can use the [Pyrostarter](https://github.com/ahmetveburak/pyrostarter) to create a bot project.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you may get this error is forgetting to declare a method `async`

```
def main():
  # do something

asyncio.run(main())
```

Just change to

```
async def main():
  # do something

asyncio.run(main())
```